# Create defaults to use in return in shortcode - Wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins, return, shortcode

I'm making my first plugin to Wordpress which adds a shortcode that I can use in my header.

The plugin integrates with Wordpress option page. All admin related works fine including writing top wp_options table and/or delete/update fields.

My problem is in the custom shortcode itself (at the bottom).

What I want to achieve is, when get_option('bfcsc_logout_link') is not set in admin, a default value should be returned.

And of course, I am looking for the 'nice way', so my code looks good as well :) When the plugin works as I want to in the end, I'm thinking about taking it a step further and separate the code into init files etc, making it more professional.

Below is the full code (excluding assets):

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Brokenfruit Custom Login Shortcode
Plugin URI: https://www.brokenfruit.dk/
Description: Adds custom login shortcode for Brokenfruit
Version: 1.0
Author: Kenn Nielsen
Author URI: https://www.brokenfruit.dk/
License: GPL
*/

// Meaning of abbreviations:
// bfclsc = brokenfruit custom login shortcode


/* Register styles and scripts */

function bfcsc_enqueue_scripts() {
    global $wpdb;
    $screen = get_current_screen();

    if ( $screen->id != 'settings_page_brokenfruit-custom-shortcodes' ) 
        return; // exit if incorrect screen id

        wp_enqueue_style( 'brokenfruit-shortcodes-styles', plugins_url( '/css/styles.css', __FILE__ ) );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', plugins_url( '/css/bootstrap.css', __FILE__ ) );
        wp_enqueue_script('admin_js_bootstrap_hack', plugins_url( '/scripts/bootstrap-hack.js', __FILE__ ), false, '1.0.0', false);

}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'bfcsc_enqueue_scripts' );

/* Runs when plugin is activated */
register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'bfcsc_install');

/* Runs on plugin deactivation*/
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'bfcsc_remove' );

function bfcsc_install() {
    /* Creates new database field */
    add_option('bfcsc_logout_link', '', '', 'yes');
    add_option('bfcsc_login_link', '', '', 'yes');
    add_option('bfcsc_account_link', '', '', 'yes');
}

function bfcsc_remove() {
    /* Deletes the database field */
    delete_option('bfcsc_logout_link');
    delete_option('bfcsc_login_link');
    delete_option('bfcsc_account_link');
}

if (is_admin() ) {
    function add_bfcsc_option_page() {
        add_options_page(
            'Brokenfruit Custom Shortcodes',    // The text to be displayed in the title tag
            'Brokenfruit Custom Shortcodes',    // The text to be used for the menu
            'administrator',                    // The capability required to display this menu
            'brokenfruit-custom-shortcodes',    // The unique slug name to refer to this menu
            'bfcsc_html_page');                 // The function tooutput the page content
    }
    /* Call the html code */
    add_action('admin_menu', 'add_bfcsc_option_page');
}

function bfcsc_html_page(){
    ?>
    <form method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php wp_nonce_field('update-options'); ?>
        <div class="bootstrap-wrapper">
            <div class="row top-buffer">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div><h1>Brokenfruit Custom Login Shortcode</h1></div>
                    <p>Til brug for shortcode:<br/><span class="shortcode-preview">[custom_login]</span></p>
                    <div class="top-buffer"></div>
                    <h5>Link til log ud:</h5><input placeholder="Eksempel: wp-login.php?action=logout" class="form-control" name="bfcsc_logout_link" type="text" id="bfcsc_logout_link" value="<?php echo get_option('bfcsc_logout_link'); ?>" /></td>
                    <div class="top-buffer"></div>
                    <h5>Link til log ind:</h5><input placeholder="Eksempel: /log-ind/" class="form-control" name="bfcsc_login_link" type="text" id="bfcsc_login_link" value="<?php echo get_option('bfcsc_login_link'); ?>" /></td>
                    <div class="top-buffer"></div>
                    <h5>Link til min konto:</h5><input placeholder="Eksempel: /min-brokenfruit/" class="form-control" name="bfcsc_account_link" type="text" id="bfcsc_account_link" value="<?php echo get_option('bfcsc_account_link'); ?>" /></td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="page_options" value="bfcsc_logout_link,bfcsc_login_link,bfcsc_account_link" />
                    <input class="btn btn-primary top-buffer" type="submit" value="<?php _e('Save Changes') ?>" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <?php
}

/*---------------------------------------------------*/
/*          Custom login shortcode - start           */
/*---------------------------------------------------*/

function mydefaults (){
    if (!get_option('bfcsc_logout_link')){
        $logout_link = '/log-ud/';
    } else {
        $logout_link = get_option('bfcsc_logout_link');
    }

    if (!get_option('bfcsc_login_link')){
        $login_link = '/log-ind';
    } else {
        $login_link = get_option('bfcsc_login_link');
    }

    if (!get_option('bfcsc_account_link')){
        $account_link = '/min-brokenfruit/';
    } else {
        $account_link = get_option('bfcsc_account_link');
    }
}

function custom_login_shortcode ( $atts ){

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {

        return '<a href="' . $account_link . '" class="custom_login"><i class="fa icon-user"></i>Mit Brokenfruit</a> | <a href="' . wp_logout_url( home_url()) . '" class="custom_login"><i class="fa icon-logout"></i>Log ud</a>';

    } else {

        return '<a href="/log-ind/" class="custom_login"><i class="fa icon-login"></i>Log ind</a>';
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'custom_login', 'custom_login_shortcode' );

/*---------------------------------------------------*/
/*          Custom login shortcode - end             */
/*---------------------------------------------------*/

?>
```

Thank you all in advance!
Cheers Kenn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct. Your variable was not available inside that method. 
As to the parameters, the shortcode api is not meant to work like that. The lone parameter $atts is used to pass the variables you need from the shortcode (the part inside the bracket) as an array. 
I'm not sure how you're planning to use the shortcode. But you could pass your parameters with

```
[custom_login login='different_login' ]
```

then pick them up in the shortcode in the $atts array:

```
function custom_login_shortcode ( $atts ){
 $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'login' => '/log-ind/', // default value for login
        'account' => '/min-brokenfruit/', // default value for account
    ), $atts ); 

return $a['login']; // returns 'different_login'
return $a['account'] // returns  '/min-brokenfruit/'
```

You could also define your variables as constants (with a global scope) so they are available inside your shortcode and all your methods:
    define('MY_LOGIN_LINK','/log-ind');
Then you can use if (!defined('MY_LOGIN_LINK')) to see if you have something to work with. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php for more on that.

But if you only need these values in this one method, this would work in your re-written code to streamline it a little:
    $login_link = get_option('bfclsc_login_link','/log-ind/');

Answer (score 0):

get_option() has an optional parameter for a default value:

```
$no_exists_value = get_option( 'no_exists_value', 'default_value' );
var_dump( $no_exists_value ); /* outputs 'default_value' */
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option

Comment: That I can use. Please tell me why, when I test:

    $account_link = get_option('bfclsc_account_link','/min-brokenfruit/');
    var_dump($account_link);
it outputs string(0) "" ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

I needed to put the content of function mydefaults into the function custom_login_shortcode. I guess my variables was created in the global state and could not be used?

After all, I don't understand why I could not pass the variables into the shortcode like:

```
function custom_login_shortcode ( $atts, $logout_link, $login_link, $account_link ){
```

Below is the working shortcode function:

```
/*---------------------------------------------------*/
/*          Custom login shortcode - start           */
/*---------------------------------------------------*/

/*function mydefaults (){
    if (!get_option('bfclsc_logout_link')){
        $logout_link = '/log-ud/';
    } else {
        $logout_link = get_option('bfclsc_logout_link');
    }

    if (!get_option('bfclsc_login_link')){
        $login_link = '/log-ind';
    } else {
        $login_link = get_option('bfclsc_login_link');
    }

    if (!get_option('bfclsc_account_link')){
        $account_link = '/min-brokenfruit/';
    } else {
        $account_link = get_option('bfclsc_account_link');
    }
}*/

function custom_login_shortcode ( $atts ){

    if (!get_option('bfclsc_logout_link')){
        $logout_link = wp_logout_url( home_url()); //call wordpress logout with home redirect: wp_logout_url( home_url()) 
    } else {
        $logout_link = get_option('bfclsc_logout_link');
    }

    if (!get_option('bfclsc_login_link')){
        $login_link = '/log-ind/';
    } else {
        $login_link = get_option('bfclsc_login_link');
    }

    if (!get_option('bfclsc_account_link')){
        $account_link = '/min-brokenfruit/';
    } else {
        $account_link = get_option('bfclsc_account_link');
    }

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {

        return '<a href="' . $account_link . '" class="custom_login"><i class="fa icon-user"></i>Mit Brokenfruit</a> | <a href="' . $logout_link . '" class="custom_login"><i class="fa icon-logout"></i>Log ud</a>';

    } else {

        return '<a href="' . $login_link . '" class="custom_login"><i class="fa icon-login"></i>Log ind</a>';
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'custom_login', 'custom_login_shortcode' );

/*---------------------------------------------------*/
/*          Custom login shortcode - end             */
/*---------------------------------------------------*/
```